# couldn't grab input element from a website

Tags: javascript, css, puppeteer

so I'm trying to get an input element from Twitter but when I run it, it keeps giving me an error like this in the node terminal, as a result, a browser window made from this code will close itself because it doesn't find the right input selector. how do I grab the right kind of input?

`Error: No element found for selector: input[name="text"]`

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
  })
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  page.setViewport({
    width: 1280,
    height: 800,
    isMobile: false
  })
  await page.goto("https://twitter.com/i/flow/login");
  await page.type('input[name="text"]', 'username', {delay: 25})
})();
```

[image: the input that i cant grab]

i tried different selectors including `class` attribute but still gets error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to [waitForSelector](https://pptr.dev/api/puppeteer.page.waitforselector/) to appear on the page before typing. That is why you got an error, it couldn't find the element.

```js
  await page.waitForSelector('input[name="text"]');
  await page.type('input[name="text"]', 'username', {delay: 25})
```

[image]